# C++ precision of numbers and truncation with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, truncate, floating-point-precision, digits

I have a file.txt with hundreds of numbers.
They have many digits (max 20) after the point and I need to get them all without truncation, otherwise they introduce errors in the following computations. I made these numbers with matlab so it has a monstrous precision but now I must replicate this behaviour in my program.

I've done this way:

```
 fstream in;
 in.open(file.txt, ios::in);
 long double number;
 in>>number;
```

I also tried this

```
 in.precision(20);
 in>>number;
```

before each ">>" operation but it is vain

Comment: You are out of luck on this - commonly, `long double` has only 18 digit precision ([link to a demo that shows you how to determine precision on your own system](http://ideone.com/vFq0yK)).

Comment: `precision()` is for printing, not reading. Your compiler might provide a nonstandard 128-bit floating point type, or you can use an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: if i copy and past these numbers on my code all goes well but I can't do this with hundreds of numbers and files

Comment: A question: Are the matlab-values precise (they might be printed with 20 digits and loose precision earlier)?

Comment: Following @Dieter's line of thought, the default data type in Matlab is typically 64-bit double.

Comment: they don't loose precision, if I print them in my code assigning to a long double, all goes well so it must be a problem of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine on my system (Win7, VS2012):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
    std::ifstream file ("test.txt") ;

    long double d = 0 ;
    file >> d ;

    std::cout.precision (20) ;
    std::cout << d << "\n" ;


    return 0 ;
}
```

The text file:

> > 2.7239385667867091

The output:

> > 2.7239385667867091

If this doesn't work on your system, then you need to use a third-party number library.

Comment: ok, I can get the same output, but the computations with these numbers are incorrect in the end. is there a difference between output precision and computation precision?

Comment: the computations are correct, if I put manually the numbers.
I think all is due to this loading

Comment: @user3290180 Yes there is a possible difference between output precision and computation precision. Your debugger can tell you if there is a problem with the loading. Perhaps you should edit your question to show a small concise example of the computation not working. I have a feeling that looking at the assembly code will show you why one is right and the other isn't.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>[`std::numeric_limits::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min)</strike> [`std::numeric_limits::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) can tell you what your target's actual precision is for `long double`.

If you find that it's insufficient to represent your data, you probably want arbitrary precision.  There are a couple of arbitrary precision number libraries you can use, none of which are standard in C++.

- [`boost::multiprecision`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)
- [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/)
- [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/)

Comment: long double: 3.3621e-4932
one of my numbers is 2.7239385667867091
how can I read all its digits? if I paste this number in my code, all goes well as it were matlab so it must be a problem of functions, not precision, isn't it?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits::min` tells you the smallest representable number, not the precision. `std::numeric_limits::digits10` tells you the precision (i.e., the maximum number of significant digits).